# How to move caret position to end of current word?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm using a webbrowser control. How can I move the insert position for an execCommand to the end of the word, that is currently selected?

Example:

| <- current caret position

Som|eword   -> move -> Someword|  -> execCommand executes after current word

What I want to do is insert a line without braking the word. What happens now is:

Somew|ord -> line

Somew

---

ord

What should happen is:

Somew|ord -> line

---

Someword

Answer (score 0):

This is so hacky that I'm almost embarrassed to post it, but ... you can accomplish "Inserting a line without breaking the word" "using a webbrowser control" by doing something like

```
webBrowser1.Url = 
            new Uri("javascript:" +
                "var tr=document.selection.createRange();" +
                "tr.expand('word');" +
                "tr.collapse(false);" +
                // "tr.select();" // Necessary to actually move the caret
                "tr.pasteHTML('<hr>');");
```

After the webbrowser has loaded the document that you want to manipulate, and the user has selected the text that they'd like to insert a line after. If you really need the caret moved as well, you'd need a `tr.select()` after the `tr.collapse()`.

It doesn't use the execCommand though, so it may not be suitable for your purposes. Maybe someone else can figure out a way to make this a little cleaner...